# Any easy way to alter the data that comes from a mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql

so I'm using mysql to grab data from a database and feeding it into a python function.  I import mysqldb, connect to the database and run a query like this:

```
conn.query('SELECT info FROM bag')
x = conn.store_result()

for row in x.fetch_row(100):
    print row
```

but my problem is that my data comes out like this (1.234234,)(1.12342,)(3.123412,)

when I really want it to come out like this: 1.23424, 1.1341234, 5.1342314 (i.e. without parenthesis).  I need it this way to feed it into a python function.  Does anyone know how I can grab data from the database in a way that doesn't have parenthesis?

Answer (score 2):

Rows are returned as tuples, even if there is only one column in the query. You can access the first and only item as `row[0]`

The first time around in the `for` loop, `row` does indeed refer to the first row. The second time around, it refers to the second row, and so on.

By the way, you say that you are using `mySQLdb`, but the methods that you are using are from the underlying `_mysql` library (low level, scarcely portable) ... why??

Comment: hey it works! thanks,  but I don't get it, I thought row[0] would only return the first row?  At least that's how it would appear to me, why isn't that right?

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply use this as your for loop:

```
for (info, ) in x.fetch_row(100):
    print info
```

Comment: ... except that `row` is now a rather inappropriate name